# Node filter by stroke color in d3 tree view

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I have list of circle. I have to filter circle that based on color without updating the tree. Basically I want to show hide circle and their path. I google it but did not found any predefined method in d3.js. How can I achieve that, what approach will be better for this requirement. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nuhw5r9/1/)
[image]

**Edit**
I have a three link. Red, Green and yellow. When user click on green or any of these link then node which have same color should show and rest of the node should hide. for Example if I click on green then green node should show.

```
var treeData=[{
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "value": 10,
    "type": "black",
    "level": "red",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "value": 15,
        "type": "grey",
        "level": "red",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A",
            "value": 5,
            "type": "steelblue",
            "level": "orange"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A",
            "value": 8,
            "type": "steelblue",
            "level": "red"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "value": 10,
        "type": "grey",
        "level": "green"
      }
    ]
  }]
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't get, what exactly you want to do.Could you explain it a little more

Comment: I have added my question